# UX Organisation

Tags: guidelines, standards, conventions, organizations

I was just wondering if there are any organisations or groups which monitor or provide insight into User eXperience, such as the W3C for the World Wide Web, or the IEEE? Although they are not creators of laws, they can be looked at for direction and regulation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Usability Professionals Association - http://www.upassoc.org/

Interaction Design Association: http://www.ixda.org/

Information Architecture Institute http://iainstitute.org/

You also need to check the websites with regard to your country/city - the UPA and IxDA have many local branches. Also, some other countries have local organization unrelated to these.

Answer (score 2):

The Information Architecture Institute http://iainstitute.org/ may fit this category. They provide insight and direction, no regulation and rules.

Answer (score 2):

The Usability Professionals Association may be of interest:

http://www.upassoc.org/